# Undefined ID after inserting into MySQL

Tags: php

I'm new in PHP. Can anyone tell me why `Dept_ID` didn't show up after inserting data into database.

Data viewing page:

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>View Records</title>
    </head>

    <body>
    <div id="container">
    <center> <h2> SECTION RECORD </h2> </center>
    <?php

    // connect to the database
    include('connection.php');

     // get results from database
     $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM section") 
     or die(mysql_error());  

        // display data in table

      echo "<table border='1' cellpadding='20' cellspacing='0' 
      align = center>";
      echo "<tr> <th>Department ID</th><th>Section ID</th> 
      <th>Section Description</th> <th> </th><th> </th>";

      // loop through results of database query, displaying them in the table
       while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) {

       // echo out the contents of each row into a table

        echo "<tr>
                <td align = center>".$row['Dept_ID']."</th> 
                <td align = center>".$row['Section_ID']."</th> 
                <td align = center>".$row['Section_Desc']."</th> 

                <td><a href='Update_Dept.php?Dept_ID=$row[Dept_ID]
                &Section_ID=$row[Section_ID]
                &Section_Desc=$row[Section_Desc]'>Update</a></td>

                <td><a href='Delete_Section.php?Dept_ID=$row[Dept_ID]     
                '>Delete</a></td>

        </tr>";
    }   

 echo "<a href = 'New_Section.php'>Add new record </a>"

 ?>

 </div>
 </div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Add new record page:

```
    <form action = "New_Section_Process.php" method = "POST">
    <table border = "1"  cellpadding='10' cellspacing='0'  align = "center">
    <tr>
    <th colspan = '3'>
    <font color = "black">Section</font></th>
    </tr>

    <?php
    include("connection.php");
    ?>

    <tr>

    <td>Department ID : </td> 
    <td> <select Dept_ID="dept">
    <?php
    $query = "SELECT * FROM dept ORDER BY Dept_ID";
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    if(mysql_num_rows($result)) {
        while ($id = mysql_fetch_row($result))

            {
                echo "<option value='" . $id[1] . "'>" . $id[0] . " " . 
                $id[1] . " </option>";

            }

    } else {
        echo "<option value=''>No Department </option>";
    }
  ?>
    </select>
  </td> 
  </tr>



  <tr>
  <td>Section ID :</td>
  <td><input type = "varchar" name = "Section_ID"
  maxlength = "55" placeholder = "Enter Here">

  </td>

  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td>Section Description :</td>
  <td><input type = "varchar" name = "Section_Desc"
  maxlength = "55" placeholder = "Enter Here">
  </td>
  </tr>

  <td colspan = "3" align = "center">
  <input type = "submit" name = "submit" 
  value = "Submit">
  </td>
  </tr>

  </table>
  </form>
```

Code for adding new record:

```
     <a href = "View_Section.php">Back Section</a>
     <form action = "New_Section_Process.php" method = "POST">
     <table align = "center">

     <?php

     $Dept_ID = '';

     //connection to database
     include("connection.php");

     $Dept_ID = $_POST['Dept_ID'];
     $Section_ID = $_POST['Section_ID'];
     $Section_Desc = $_POST['Section_Desc'];

     echo "$Dept_ID, $Section_ID, $Section_Desc";


     //creating SQL statements

     $query = "INSERT INTO section (Dept_ID, Section_ID, Section_Desc)     
     VALUES('$Dept_ID', '$Section_ID', '$Section_Desc')";

    {

    {   //run the SQL statement
        //mysql_query is the function that is used to run query
    if(mysql_query($query))
    {

        header('location:View_Section.php');
    }
    else
    {
        //error if query is not valid
        echo "Data Already Exist!";
            }
        }

    }




   ?>
```

After I submit the form, I receive an error saying undefined `Dept_ID`.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have no Dept_ID elements in your form. $_GET/$_POST/$_REQUEST receive data if a :input is set with `name="Dept_ID"`

Set

```
<select name="Dept_ID">
```

Answer (score 0):

You have not specified name attribute of your combobox.

It should be as follows:

```
<select name="Dept_ID">
```

Answer (score 0):

This part won't echo the GET parameters:

```
    echo "<tr>
            <td align = center>".$row['Dept_ID']."</th> 
            <td align = center>".$row['Section_ID']."</th> 
            <td align = center>".$row['Section_Desc']."</th> 

            <td><a href='Update_Dept.php?Dept_ID=$row[Dept_ID]
            &Section_ID=$row[Section_ID]
            &Section_Desc=$row[Section_Desc]'>Update</a></td>

            <td><a href='Delete_Section.php?Dept_ID=$row[Dept_ID]     
            '>Delete</a></td>

    </tr>";
```

You'll need to concat the string with the variable instead:

```
    echo "<tr>
            <td align = center>".$row['Dept_ID']."</th> 
            <td align = center>".$row['Section_ID']."</th> 
            <td align = center>".$row['Section_Desc']."</th> 

            <td><a href='Update_Dept.php?Dept_ID=" . $row['Dept_ID'] . "
            &Section_ID=" . $row['Section_ID'] . "
            &Section_Desc=" . $row['Section_Desc'] . "'>Update</a></td>

            <td><a href='Delete_Section.php?Dept_ID=" . $row['Dept_ID'] .      
            '>Delete</a></td>

    </tr>";
```

---

Similarly, this will also not echo the values of the variables:

```
echo "$Dept_ID, $Section_ID, $Section_Desc";
```

Output:

> $Dept_ID, $Section_ID, $Section_Desc

To echo the values, you'll need to concat then instead:

```
echo $Dept_ID . $Section_ID . $Section_Desc;
```

---

`Dept_ID` does not exist in HTML:

```
<select Dept_ID="dept">
```

You'll need to use `name` instead:

```
<select name="Dept_ID">
```

---

**Tip: Do not use `mysql_*` functions as they are deprecated. Use `mysqli_*` instead.**